# react components keeps re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, semantic-ui, react-google-maps

hey everyone I'm having re-render issues with my component. every time page loads CISW308Assignment5 component renders. Then the .map functions renders 5 times. After that user is prompted for using geolocation services, and everything re-renders again.

the idea behind this madness:

on page load user is prompter for geolocation. it is stored incase user will later request directions to any of the places. page has dropdown list of some places. each dropdown contains basic info about the place. phone info is a link, and on a mobile device when clicked on; will prompt user if they want to initiate a call. address info is a link to that place on google maps. show map button opens a modal, and with the pre-coded coordinates the map center and pins that location. the modal contains get direction button which when you click on sends user to google maps website. along with the redirect it sends your coordinates and the places coordinates to get the directions.

CISW305Assignment5.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import Template from 'layout/Template';
import Assignment from 'components/Assignment';
import ExtraCredit from 'components/ExtraCredit';
import Submissions from 'components/Submissions';
import { Accordion, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Boudin, Chilis, InNout, PandaExpress, PaneraBread } from 'assets';
import MapModal from 'components/MapModal';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const assignment = [
  {
    completed: true,
    name: 'a clickable “SHOW MAP” buttons or links for 2 or more Locations that opens a “map page” for each of your food locations.'
  }
];

const extracredit = [
  {
    completed: true,
    name: `a clickable “GET DIRECTIONS” link or button on each map page, that links to another map with directions from the users' current location to the restaurant location.`
  }
];
const favoritePlaces = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    src: Boudin,
    name: 'Boudin Bakery',
    phoneNumber: '(916) 973-1849',
    phoneNumberLink: 'tel:+1-916-973-1849',
    address: '2573 Fair Oaks Blvd, Sacramento, CA 95825',
    addressLink:
      'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Boudin+SF/@38.5749736,-121.4019994,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x809ada557d7929af:0x4b8201a127d64751!8m2!3d38.5749736!4d-121.4019994',
    placeCoords: { lat: 38.57498557564539, lng: -121.40199854938247 }
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    src: InNout,
    name: 'In-N-Out',
    phoneNumber: '(800) 786-1000',
    phoneNumberLink: 'tel:+1-800-786-1000',
    address: '3501 Truxel Rd, Sacramento, CA 95834',
    addressLink: 'https://goo.gl/maps/5rtssiGZb2KyLQpKA',
    placeCoords: { lat: 38.63682135923305, lng: -121.5041714687768 }
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    src: Chilis,
    name: `Chili's`,
    phoneNumber: '(916) 285-8703',
    phoneNumberLink: 'tel:+1-916-285-8703',
    address: '3870 Truxel Rd, Sacramento, CA 95834',
    addressLink: 'https://goo.gl/maps/iFCDnk23ywRSH5HN7',
    placeCoords: { lat: 38.6385674159852, lng: -121.50372754232959 }
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    src: PandaExpress,
    name: 'Panda Express',
    phoneNumber: '(916) 575-8927',
    phoneNumberLink: 'tel:+1-916-575-8927',
    address: '3571 N Freeway Blvd, Sacramento, CA 95834',
    addressLink: 'https://goo.gl/maps/qwzi1SxXbahKDNKd8',
    placeCoords: { lat: 38.640220171851546, lng: -121.4999965846592 }
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    src: PaneraBread,
    name: 'Panera Bread',
    phoneNumber: '(916) 515-2012',
    phoneNumberLink: 'tel:+1-916-515-2012',
    address: '3571 N Freeway Blvd, Sacramento, CA 95834',
    addressLink: 'https://goo.gl/maps/erkno1X3d68db3BK9',
    placeCoords: { lat: 38.6402061514062, lng: -121.50000428469711 }
  }
];

const CISW308Assignment5: FC = () => {
  const [userCoords, setUserCoords] = useState<{
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  }>({
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  });

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveIndex(0);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     const getLocation = () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    ({ coords }) => setUserCoords({ lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude }),
    ({ message }) => {
      alert(`${message}. Please try enabling Geolocation services.`);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    }
  );
};

const getUserLocation = () => {
  if (navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query) {
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(function (result) {
      const permission = result.state;
      if (permission === 'granted' || permission === 'prompt') {
        getLocation();
      }
    });
  } else if (navigator.geolocation) {
    getLocation();
  } else {
    alert("Unfortunately geolocation services aren't supported by your browser");
  }
};
getUserLocation();
  }, []);

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const handleClick = (e: any, titleProps: any) => {
    const { index } = titleProps;

    const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index;

    setActiveIndex(newIndex);
  };
  console.log('i rendered');

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>CISW 308 - Assignment 5</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Template>
        <Assignment assignment={assignment} />
        <ExtraCredit assignment={extracredit} />
        <Submissions>
          <Accordion fluid styled style={{ maxWidth: '550px' }}>
            {favoritePlaces.map((place, index) => {
              console.log('i rendered');
              return (
                <div key={place.id}>
                  <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === index} index={index} onClick={handleClick}>
                    <Image style={{ maxWidth: '30px' }} src={place.src} />
                    {place.name}
                  </Accordion.Title>
                  <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === index}>
                    Phone Number: <a href={place.phoneNumberLink}>{place.phoneNumber}</a>
                    <br />
                    Address:{' '}
                    <a target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' href={place.addressLink}>
                      {place.address}
                    </a>
                    <br />
                    <MapModal placeCoords={place.placeCoords} userCoords={userCoords} />
                  </Accordion.Content>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Accordion>
        </Submissions>
      </Template>
    </>
  );
};

export default CISW308Assignment5;
```

MapModal.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import MapContainer from './MapContainer';

const MapModal: FC<{
  userCoords: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };

  placeCoords: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };
}> = ({ placeCoords, userCoords }) => {
  console.log(' ~ file: MapModal.tsx ~ line 18 ~ userCoords', userCoords);
  console.log(' ~ file: MapModal.tsx ~ line 20 ~ placeCoords', placeCoords);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    try {
      window.open(
        `https://www.google.es/maps/dir/'${userCoords?.lat},${userCoords?.lng}'/'${placeCoords?.lat},${placeCoords?.lng}'`,
        '_blank',
        'noopener,noreferrer'
      );
    } catch ({ message }) {
      console.error(message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      closeIcon
      open={open}
      trigger={<Button>SHOW MAP</Button>}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
    >
      <Modal.Header style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Button onClick={handleClick}>GET DIRECTIONS</Button>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Description>
          <MapContainer placeCoords={placeCoords} />
        </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default MapModal;
```

MapContainer.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const MapContainer: FC<{
  placeCoords: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };
}> = ({ placeCoords }) => {
  console.log(' ~ file: MapContainer.tsx ~ line 11 ~ placeCoords', placeCoords);
  const mapStyles = {
    height: '500px',
    width: '100%'
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey='API_KEY'>
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={mapStyles} zoom={18} center={placeCoords}>
          <Marker position={placeCoords} />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MapContainer;
```

on page load:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8SYt.png)

page ui:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP87m.png)

map modal:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10QH8.png)

thank you for any and all help in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What is the question? Is there a problem with React rerendering? The code is console logging as an unintentional side-effect in the render method, and `favoritePlaces` is an array of length 5.... so.... seeing 5 console logs per "render cycle" tracks here.

Comment: @DrewReese wait so the component is re-rendering because there is a console.log() statement ?

Comment: No, React is just rendering because it needs to, but there's a bunch of extra console logs because you are logging in a loop. The result is 5 logs per render cycle. You say you see 5 logs, so I think the component rendered only once.

Comment: @DrewReese I see so if i remove all the extra console.log()'s that should fix it ?

Comment: Sure. ‍♂️ Try also placing your console logs in a `useEffect` hook so they actually are only called once per render cycle, i.e. `useEffect(() => console.log('i rendered'));`.

Comment: @DrewReese right now this happens on page load: 
the CISW308Assignment5 component renders
the .map fires 5 times
the MapModal fires 5 times
and then this cycle happens again, without touching anything. on page load i see 2 sets of loading. then if i press on any of the dropdowns same cycle fires. 
the CISW308Assignment5 component renders
the .map fires 5 times
the MapModal fires 5 times.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, `favoritePlaces` is an array of length 5, so any unintentional side-effects will happen 5 times, the `MapModal` component will have 5 "instances" rendered into the DOM, etc. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify any reproduction steps? I've explored around the page a bit but don't see any odd rendering issues.

Comment: @DrewReese so on initial page load, if you check the dev console you will get 2 instance of load, then if you click on any dropdown item there is some sort of glitch. its trying to pass props to GetDirections button, but GetDirections isn't called yet, so the props that are being passed are preset default.

Comment: @DrewReese anytime i reload the page, or quit the server and restart it, i get 2 instances of items rendered. then any time i click on an item i get:  ~ file: MapModal.tsx ~ line 20 ~ placeCoords {lat: 38.63686305635747, lng: -121.47572123063725}

Comment: @DrewReese then when i click on show map button i get:
 ~ file: MapModal.tsx ~ line 18 ~ userCoords {lat: MY_CORDS, lng: MY_CORDS }  ~ file: MapModal.tsx ~ line 20 ~ placeCoords {lat: 38.57498557564539, lng: -121.40199854938247}
MapContainer.tsx:18 MapContainer i rendered, and i got the : [object Object]

Comment: @DrewReese so again its trying to pass default props to get direction button which wasn't called yet.

Comment: I'm struggling to get to the UI what you describe. I'm on `"/cisw308"` that is mapping `favoritePlaces` and rendering the `MapModal`. I don't see any dropdowns, anything for directions, or any odd render issues.

Comment: @DrewReese the dropdown I was referring to are called Acordions  that's in cisw308/CISW305Assignment5.tsx 
sorry for the confusion. 
I see maybe after all that was a weird side effect of console.log()

Comment: Yeah. I'm also thinking that maybe I can't reproduce any issue partially due to an error with a missing google API key: `GOOGLE API KEY NOT FOUND!`.

Comment: @DrewReese  I see its in my .env file. 
Honestly if you can't recreate my issues, its probably me other thinking and over analyzing it and its just those stupid console.logs() just like you said in the beginning.